# Cutting an elliptical cone

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification, quadrics

An right circular cone with vertex at the origin, and with it axis pointing along the $z$ axis, is scaled (stretched) along the $y$ axis direction by a factor of $2$.  The angle between the surface of the **unstretched** cone and its axis is $20^\circ$.

A plane with equation $\sqrt{2} x + \sqrt{2} y + 2 \sqrt{3} z = 100 \sqrt{3} $ cuts through this stretched cone.  The intersection between the plane and the stretched cone is an ellipse.  Find its semi-major and semi-minor axes lengths.

[image]

**My approach:**

I took the following steps for the solution:

1. Found the equation of the (stretched) elliptical cone.
2. Parameterized the plane, using two unit perpendicular axes that span the plane.
3. Used the parametrization in the equation of the cone, to find the equation governing the parameters.  The equation is that of an ellipse.
4. Extracted the semi-axes lengths from the equation of the ellipse.

I got the semi-major axis length as $44.029848$ and the semi-minor axis length as $20.70276$.

I would like to verify these values.  I appreciate if someone with access to a CAD software would create a model for the elliptical cone and the cutting plane, and verify the lengths of semi-axes, or the area of the cut.

Your input is highly appreciated.